# how to add and remove an item in js array using string index

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi guys i want to first add item in an array using string index and later on remove that item using same strint index.
for eg

```
var array = new Array();
array['i1'] = '9807988';
array['i2'] = '9875353';
array['i3'] = '9875353';
```

And now i have index i2 and want to remove that item

```
var key = 'i2';
array.splice(key,1)
```

But this is not working in my case.Here i1,i2,...in and their values 9807988,9875353,...
are dynamic in my case.I have to remove with the key i1,i2 not with their values.Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elias is right, its actually an object, you can use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to remove property from an object

```
delete array[key];
```

Answer (score 4):

You're *not* creating an `Array` instance! JS doesn't know of associative arrays, they're objects. The moment you define an *"index"* that is not numeric, the Array becomes an Object, loosing all those goodies like `length` and typical array methods.

This is down to the fact that JS didn't have arrays at first, instead they were introduced later on. The `Array` constructor is actually just an augmentation of the `Object.prototype`. You can check this in a couple of ways:

```
var anArray = [1,2];
for(var index in anArray) console.log( typeof index);
```

This logs `string` every time, not `Number`, because internally an array is an object so all numeric indexes are coerced to strings.
This also explains why your code (using an array as an object) works without errors.

The *main* reason why using `splice` on an Object is a bad idea, even if the methods were still kicking around is that the ECMAScript specifications don't enforce a given order in which the properties have to be added to the obejct. Chrome's V8 engine, for example, sorts them alphabetically, but you have *no guarantees* that other engines do the same thing, so your code will behave unpredictably.

*Note:*
Don't use `new Array`, as it can suprize you from time to time:

```
var someNumber = 213;
var a = new Array();//same as a = [];
var b = new Array(someNumber);// NOT the same as b = [someNumber]
console.log(b.length);//213!!!!
console.log(b);//[undefined, undefined, undefined,....]
var c = new Array(someNumber + '');//THE SAME as b = [someNumber + '']
console.log(c);//['213']
```

so depending on what you pass to the array constructor, the resulting array can look different from what you expected it to look like.
As for your code, write:

```
var yourObject = { i1: '9807988',
                   i2: '9875353',
                   i3: '9875353'};
delete(yourObject.i2);
//or
delete(yourObject['i2']);
```

And read up on what you can do with objects on MDN

Comment: According to the [ECMAScript Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4) a property name `P` is an array index if and only if `ToString(ToUint32(P))` is equal to `P`.

Comment: @Korikulum: Yes, and in what way did I contradict that? Some value => convert to unsigned 32 bit int => TO STRING is the index...

Comment: You misunderstood me, I was just giving a link to the specs.

Answer (score -1):

here a [DEMO to remove item](http://jsfiddle.net/demo_Ashif/LeCYg/)

```
 var array = new Array();
 array[0] = '9807988';
 array[1] = '9875353';
 array[2] = '9875353';


 var key = 1;
 array.splice(key,1)

for(i=0;i<array.length; i++)
{ document.write(array[i]);
  document.write('</br>');
}
```

Comment: Wrong on so many levels... not in the least: `document.write`